# How to avoid "redundant" assume?

Tags: maxima

The first time an [assumption](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_11.html#assume) is made, a summary is output:

```
(%i1) assume(a>0);
(%o1)                               [a > 0]
```

But if the same assumption is given again, "redundant" is given, instead of the summary:

```
(%i2) assume(a >0);
(%o2)                             [redundant]
```

I would like a second execution to give exactly the same output as the first one. Otherwise the texmacs session becomes cluttered with "redundants" that are only distracting.

The [`forget`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_11.html#forget) does that, but it is cumbersome to give `a > 0` twice.

```
(%i6) forget(a > 0);
(%o6)                               [a > 0]
(%i7) assume(a >0);
(%o7)                               [a > 0]
```

or even

```
(%i5) forget(a > 0)$ assume(a >0);
(%o6)                               [a > 0]
```

Suppression of the output is an acceptable workaround

```
(%i4) assume(a >0)$
```

But the summary is a nicely readable in texmacs.
Is there a way to get it, even upon redundant calls ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you say here. A couple of ideas that might help: `facts();` returns the current list of facts. Also `ctxt:supcontext();` creates a new context (set of facts). `killcontext(ctxt);` reverts to the previous facts. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier This is an interesting workaround (together with output suppression from `assume`). Thanks !

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works for you. Note that `supcontext` is not just a workaround -- it is very useful for creating (and destroying via `killcontext`) a collection of facts which is relevant only in a limited context. E.g. in a function body. See also `newcontext`.